# pyspark: couldn't find the local file

Tags: python, hadoop, apache-spark, filesystems, pyspark

I have the following simple python code:

```
from __future__ import print_function

import sys
from operator import add

from pyspark import SparkContext


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(len(sys.argv))
    if len(sys.argv) < 2:
        print("Usage: wordcount <file>", file=sys.stderr)
        exit(-1)
    sc = SparkContext(appName="PythonWordCount")
    lines = sc.textFile(sys.argv[2], 1)
    counts = lines.flatMap(lambda x: x.split(' ')).map(lambda x: (x, 1)).reduceByKey(add)
    output = counts.collect()
    for (word, count) in output:
        print("%s: %i" % (word, count))

    sc.stop()
```

Then I tried to run it on a local cluster by doing:

```
spark-submit --master spark://rws-lnx-sprk01:7077 /home/edamameQ/wordcount.py wordcount /home/edamameQ/wordTest.txt
```

the wordTest.txt is definitely available:

```
edamameQ@spark-cluster:~$ ls
data    jars   myJob.txt  wordTest.txt  wordcount.py
```

But I keep getting the errors:

```
Driver stacktrace:
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1283)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1271)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1270)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
 :
 :
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: File file:/home/edamameQ/wordTest.txt does not exist
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.getFileStatus(RawLocalFileSystem.java:520)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FilterFileSystem.getFileStatus(FilterFileSystem.java:398)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem$ChecksumFSInputChecker.<init>(ChecksumFileSystem.java:137)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem.open(ChecksumFileSystem.java:339)
```

The same code was working on AWS with the input file from a s3 location. Is there anything I need to adjust for running on a local cluster? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

File you want to read has to be accessible on all the workers. If this is a local file the only option is to keep a copy per worker machine.

Comment: Thanks! But how come when I ran the spark job in Scala, I don't need to give the file to all workers? In Scala, I just put the file in one location and it works correctly. Is there a difference between pyspark and spark in scala? Thanks!

Comment: There shouldn't be. Could you describe your configuration?

Comment: The local spark cluster is installed as standalone mode with spark 1.5.1. It has one master and 5 slaves. I put all the required input text files in the master node local disk. I have a spark job in scala, which reads in the files in the local disk, make RDD, its a more complicated job and works fine. Now I am trying to test pyspark on the cluster, but it couldn't find the file. Even I just take the file which was used and worked fine in another scala job, it just can not find it in the above pyspark job. Please let me know if there is any additional info I should provide. Thanks!

Comment: Just copy the file to the workers and see if it resolves the problem.

Comment: You are right! It works after I copy the same file to all workers! Thank you! Now the strange thing is why pyspark needs it but scala/java spark doesn't need to do that ...

Comment: I am pretty sure it needs that as well :) Generally speaking any kind of distributed file system is useful even in a standalone mode. For small things you can use `SparkFiles` from within your script but it is not useful for passing main data,