# Local file upload failed in spark application

Tags: apache-spark

In my code, I am trying to load a file which is in my local machine into spark application,
sc.textFile("file:///home/testpath/file1“).

When I submit the job on the command line

Scenario 1: spark submit --class … master local

Job ran successfully with out any  issues.

Scenario 2 : spark submit --class …. —master yarn —deploy-mode cluster

Job failed by throwing file:///home/testpath/file1 file not found  Exception.

But when I tested file1.... File exists on my local.

Scenario 3 : spark submit —class … —master yarn —deploy-mode client

Job failed by throwing file:///home/testpath/file1 file not found  Exception.

But when I tested file1,, File exists on my local.

Scenario 4: spark-shell —master=yarn

Val file1 = sc.textFile("file:///home/testpath/file1“).

Job failed by throwing file:///home/testpath/file1 file not found  Exception.

In core-site.xml, fs.default.name property set  to hdfs://mynamenode:9000

Could you please help how can I load local file in my  spark application( Using spark 2.X version)

Any Ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Spark will look for `file:///home/testpath/file1` on the driver host, which in case of yarn/cluster-mode can be any of the nodes in the cluster.

Comment: So you need to use a resource that can be accessed from the cluster nodes.

Comment: right , but scenario 3 is also failed, even though deployment mode is client.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [pyspark: couldn't find the local file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34051598/pyspark-couldnt-find-the-local-file)

Answer (score 0):

When spark execution mode is local, spark executor jobs are scheduled on the same local node and hence, it is able to find the file. But, when in yarn mode, executor jobs are scheduled randomly on any of the cluster nodes. So, you may either move your file to HDFS or maintain a copy of this file on each node

Comment: Right, But If we pass master = local and deploy-mode = client whether it will not help me reading files from local?

Comment: I believe, deploy-mode option is supported, only when you specify master=yarn. Deploy-mode decides, on which node, should the spark driver process be launched i.e. when deploy mode is client, driver process is spawned on client machine and when in cluster mode, driver process is spawned randomly on any of the cluster node